# How to download the file in selected folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using asp.net mvc. I am letting the users to download certain files. In that he will choose a file to download. Then the selected files should be downloaded to that folder.
Hope you understand my question.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: no on button click users will navigate to the path of the folder. so that the file will download to that folder

Comment: Your question is confusing. Where does the file go? From the server to the users computer? (in that case, you cannot select the folder where you want the download to go, instead the user will select himself.)

Comment: Yah the user will select the path where he want to save the file. But i will display the path where he download the next time.

Answer (score 0):

create one method which will return the document based on id

convert that file to bytes and
upload folder is the path where user selects to download

```
Document document = documentService.GetSingle(id);
byte[] fileContent = StreamFile(uploadFolder + document.FilePath);
contenttype="application/force-download";
return File(fileContent, ContentType, document.FileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Trigger-file-downloads-with-a-MVC-3-controller-action.aspx) article nad [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79043/An-Example-ASP-NET-MVC-Web-Project-to-Upload-and-D)

```
using System.IO;
namespace FileDownloadInMvc3.Models
{
    public static class ExtensionMethods
    {
        public static byte[] GetFileData(this string fileName, string filePath)
        {
            var fullFilePath = string.Format("{0}/{1}", filePath, fileName);
            if (!File.Exists(fullFilePath))
                throw new FileNotFoundException("The file does not exist.", 
                    fullFilePath);
            return File.ReadAllBytes(fullFilePath);
        }
    }
}
```